# How do I convert ldi R17, 129 to machine code

Tags: avr, memory, cpu, state-machines

What I got was 1110 1000 0001 0001 when I converted it to machine language. Is that right? Also what are the CPU activity steps and where am I going to use the address 0xF000?

Is this the right CPU activity steps?

```
PC is 0xF000
   MAR - PC = 0xF000
   0xC000 placed on address bus by MAR
   CPU issues READ command to memory
   next address is returned on the data bus
   PC is incremented by 2
```

Comment: The instruction machine code does not indicate the location in memory of the instruction - LDI R17, 129 will have the same binary code regardless of where it is in memory.

Comment: So what you're saying is the memory address doesn't matter? Well if that's the case then what are the CPU steps for ldi r17, 129?

Comment: What do you mean by "the CPU activity steps"?

Comment: Re edited post: where do you get 0xC000?  If the PC contains 0xF000, that value is placed on the address bus, so the instruction is fetched, via the data bus, from memory location 0xF000.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction "LDI R17, 129" means load the immediate data 129 into Register 17.  (Immediate data is data included in the instruction word.)

The CPU will fetch the instuction word from memory into the Instruction Register, decode the instruction, then extract the register number and immediate data, and place the immediate data in the selected register.

Note that although the AVR microcontrollers have 32 registers (0 - 31), LDI and some other instructions can only operate on registers 16 - 31, so only four bits are required to specify the register - the leading "1" is assumed.

Comment: So when I'm writing out the detailed CPU activity steps, what do I do with the address 0xF000

Comment: If the instruction is located at 0xF000, then you can just say that the CPU fetches the instruction from that location.  The program counter is a register in the CPU that always contains the address of the next instruction.  In this case, the PC contains 0xF000, so it fetches the instruction from that address, then increments the PC (by 2, I think, since a full instruction is 16 bits).

Comment: So is this right for the detailed CPU activity steps? (see edited post)